# Will my garage truss and beam configuration be adequate for a room in the attic?

Tags: framing, joists, structural

I am getting ready to finish some of the space above the garage and have some questions. I am located in Pittsburgh, PA.

The garage is sloped on both sides down to the floor. I was going to utilize the space to about 4ft(knee wall) of height on both sides. This gives about 12ft of width for the floor space.

I was going to use roughly 14ft of the 20ft for the length of the room. I am going to put an exterior door at the end of the 14ft to allow access to the rest of the space for storage.  I am going to use a small heat pump for heating/cooling the space.

It is built with 2x8s for the roof and floor.  There are steel I-beams about every 90" apart under the 2x8s.

Question: Can I leave the 2x8's or do I need to put 2x10s down? Either way, it has regular plywood and will be replacing it with 3/4" tongue and groove.

Comment: Do the I-beams run perpendicular or parallel to the 2x8s?  Also, do the 2x8s run in the 14' dimension or the 20' dimension? Also, soffit venting is typically for cool air intake - what other venting is there?  Ridge vents? Gable vents? Roof deck vents?

Comment: Can you split this into two questions please, one for the structural part (with the 2x8s) and the other for the insulation and venting part?

Comment: If you already have 2x8 bottom chords on your trusses they were apparently designed for occupancy or storage load. Don't have the spec sheets?

Comment: Do the I-beams run perpendicular or parallel to the 2x8s? Also, do the 2x8s run in the 14' dimension or the 20' dimension? Also, soffit venting is typically for cool air intake - what other venting is there? Ridge vents? Gable vents? Roof deck vents? - The Ibeams run in the 14ft direction which is perpendicular to the 2x8's. There are 3 of them spaced out over the length of the garage. I am not familiar with the other vents that you asked about. I will google and follow up.   Sorry for the double post. I hit enter and it posted it!

Comment: Isherwood - Are you asking for specs of the 2x8s? They look just like whitewood 2x8's. Are 2x8 sufficient for support and flooring? The 2x8 span from iBeam to iBeam.

Comment: No. Any engineered truss rafter has a specific live and dead load design. The manufacturer is required to provide spec sheets. I'd try to get them if you don't have them. There's more to your question than whether the bottom chords can support a floor--those members are part of a truss *system*, with specific design properties.

Comment: @Jason Please add a picture. Because I think you're confused about what a truss is, what you're describing is not a truss setup at all. You have a typical rafter & joist setup with Steel I-beams supporting the joists. Meaning, that your joists are intentional framing for an intended & very sturdy floor that would just need decking or a subfloor laid down.